# Ubuntu 18.04 screen freeze and crashes every time I launch Visual Studio Code

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, visual-studio-code

I updated Ubuntu 14 days ago and have been using it trouble free for that time - in the last 24 hours though my screen would freeze and crash every time I was working with VS Code.

I've seen other recommended solutions like **allocating additional swap space using file in my root directory:** or **launching VSCode with extensions disabled (code --disable-extensions)** The first wouldn't work as i have more than 70GB and and running VS Code wouldn't eat all the cores memory.  tried to disable extensions and it didn't fix the problem.

Update: I have since uninstalled the app hoping it would fix the problem - if running VS Code is actually the problem and the freezing hasn't stopped. Do I uninstall Ubuntu if I can't restore software to 16.04?

Comment: `--disable-gpu` solved it for me (U 20.04)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that seems to have worked for me so far

I'd a similar problem. Try the following

make a copy of the grub config

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
```

open the file grub file

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

search for a line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add the following parameter to this line

```
intel_idle.max_cstate=1
```

update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot

If it doesn't work delete the property and update grub again

Comment: Did this really helps?

Comment: @Itamar yes, it worked for me

Comment: can you add explanation about why this is solving it? (for future readers)

Answer (score 0):

C-state 1 as max avoids the CPU entering on idle state as a consequence of a bad kernel space bug or condition probably produced by a graphic driver.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051